# What does this pattern mean

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I saw the following preg match statement in a piece of code

```
preg_match("/^([^&]*)/", $url, $yt_sig);
```

I am having difficulties in understand the regex pattern.I know that  `/` is the regex delimiter but what about the others characters in pattern

@zerkms

Thanks for your answer.Based on your explanation the following regex

```
"/sig=([^&]*)/"
```

So basically in `$matches[1]` it will be would be anything that is found between `sig=`and the next  `&`(Correct me if i am wrong)

Comment: This might help: http://regex101.com/r/hH1wD5

Comment: with a test string http://regex101.com/r/sT3lL0 similar to @AmalMurali

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means a string that

`^` begins
`[^&]` with anything but ampersand sign
`*` multiple times (any times, including `0`)

So basically in `$matches[1]` it will be anything from the beginning to the first `&` sign.

Comment: @user2650277: your assumption is correct indeed

Answer (score 0):

```
$/^([^&]*)/
```

means `$url` and `$yt_sin` contains these characters in their value.

Comment: @HamZa: your change didn't make it any better :-D

Comment: @zerkms: I think HamZa was only trying to fix the spelling mistakes in the answer :)

Comment: @Amal Murali: I understand that :-) Still funny though

Comment: @HamZa: You are edited the answer but it still as same :-):-)

Comment: @Satish: Your answer is incorrect though. It says: `$/^([^&]*)/ means $url and $yt_sin contains these characters in their value.` -- no, that's **not** what it means. It tries to match the `$url` string with the pattern `$/^([^&]*)/` and stores the capturing groups in `$yt_sig`. See zerkms' answer above.

Comment: I edited only the formatting, [see my previous question](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1690401#1690401) regarding wrong answers.

Comment: @Amal Murli:yeah now i know....thnx for your suggestion